# unmute.roles.has(muterole) failed

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Whenever I type the following command `//unmute`, it shows me `This member isn't muted!` although the person I specified is truly muted. I've been stuck on this command for a few hours and I can't seem to find the problem. (*The mute command is from [this](https://github.com/The-SourceCode/Discord.js-Bot-Development/blob/master/episode_6_code/commands/tempmute.js) , I changed up some things.*)

```
if (command === "mute") {

  if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("Sorry, you don't have permissions to use this!   \n (*Required permission -* __***MANAGE MESSAGES***__)")

  let tomute = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
  if (!tomute) return message.reply("Couldn't find user.");
  let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(`name`, "muted");

  //start of create role
  if (!muterole) {
    try {
      muterole = await message.guild.createRole({
        name: "muted",
        color: "#000000",
        permissions: []
      })
      message.guild.channels.forEach(async(channel, id) => {
        await channel.overwritePermissions(muterole, {
          SEND_MESSAGES: false,
          ADD_REACTIONS: false
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.stack);
    }
  }
  //end of create role
  let mutetime = args[1];
  if (!mutetime) return message.reply("You didn't specify a time!");

  await (tomute.addRole(muterole.id));
  message.channel.send(`<@${tomute.id}> has been muted for ${ms(ms(mutetime), { long:true })}`);

  setTimeout(function() {
    tomute.removeRole(muterole.id);
    message.channel.send(`<@${tomute.id}> has been unmuted!`);
  }, ms(mutetime));

}

if (command === "unmute") {

  if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("Sorry, you don't have permissions to use this!   \n (*Required permission -* __***MANAGE MESSAGES***__)")

  let unmute = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
  if (!unmute) return message.reply("Couldn't find user.");
  let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(`name`, "muted");
  if (!unmute.roles.has(muterole)) return message.channel.send("This member isn't muted!");

  await member.removeRole(muterole.id);
  message.channel.send(`<@${unmute.id}> has been unmuted!`);

}
```

Comment: Could you please share your 'mute' command? Check that you are assigning the member the `muted` role.

Comment: there you go, added the original 'mute' command

Comment: Try `if (!unmute.roles.has(muterole.id))`, `.has` is used to check whether an element with the specified key exists.

Comment: thanks, i forgot to add the '.id'. it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **[@Profit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6624953/profit)** for answering in the comment section of the main question. The problem is solved.

Add `.id` to `if (!unmute.roles.has(muterole`Here`))`.
After that, now it should look like this: `if (!unmute.roles.has(muterole.id))`.

`.has` is used to check whether an element with the specified key exists.